# Chrome: jQuery Height not Setting on First Load

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I've encountered a strange error **ONLY** in Chrome where height will not properly set on load when being set via jQuery.  The height will set find on load when the browser is refreshed, but when you open a new tab or first navigate to the page, the height is not properly set:

**wrong**:
[image: image height wrong]

**right**:
[image: Height is right]

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $grid = $(".tile-grid"),
        $homeGrid = $(".home"),
        $boxes = $grid.find("section"),
        $window = $(window);

    function resizeBoxes() {
        var boxWidth = $boxes.first().not(".active").outerWidth();
        $boxes.css("height", boxWidth);
    }

    function main() {
        $window.on("resize", function() {
            resizeBoxes();
        });
        resizeBoxes();
    }
    main();
});
```

Upon further investigation, I find that the function has been executed, but that each box has been set to have a height of `9px`, which seems to indicate that an animation may be responsible for this.  But when I remove all animations, I still get the same result...

How do I fix this?

Comment: could you create a fiddle demo for us?

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you jsfiddle of set height of div using jquery on page load.

Please visit this fiddle.(jsfiddle.net/cPHe4/2/)Change Height of Div on page load. I think this will help you.

Thanks.